# Is there a canonical currency symbol for the Battletech C-Bill?

Tags: money, battletech

I'm building a web-page for my local Battletech group that includes tools to track our stable finances (we have a heavily homebrewed campaign set on the Solaris 7 Game world that we've been playing).

At the moment, it doesn't display a currency symbol but I'd like to add in a (preferably canonically correct) currency symbol if I can. **Is the correct symbol defined in any of the sourcebooks?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as can be seen from these screenshots from [Mechwarrior online](http://mwomercs.com/), the currency symbol for C-bills is the letter 'C' with a median bar extending to the left.

[image]

[image]

I've done my best to mock up a version in photoshop using the font Franklin Gothic Heavy.

[image]

---

Interestingly, the new [BattleTech](https://store.steampowered.com/app/637090/BATTLETECH/) game, also set within the MechWarrior universe has a different symbol, a half-hexagon with a circle centre-left. The two symbols are, however, sufficiently similar that one could conceivably be an updated version of the other.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Almost looks like Euro €.

Comment: @Aegon - I suspected it was inspired by the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a canonical one.

There is the one from Mechwarrior Online, as mentioned in the other answer, but [Mechwarrior Online is not BattleTech canon](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/MechWarrior_Online#Canonicity). Still, the MWO is probably as good as you're going to get.

Also, the new "BATTLETECH" computer game uses a different currency symbol from MWO. It's also an official product, but the video games are explicitly not canon, but they said [the storyline IS canon](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/BattleTech_(Video_Game)#Canonicity). Depending on how pedantic you want to be that could be just the story, or the symbology as well (but I think probably not).

So: use whatever you like.

Comment: Hmm. The linked wiki (and chat) seem to suggest that some elements of the game *are* considered canon.

Comment: Specifically, the hero mech descriptions only. The rest is "apocrypha". I don't know what the practical implications are between canon and apocrypha for the purposes of a game of Battletech, but there it is.